# `reflect.Kind()` of Slice Becomes `Struct` When Stored Inside Pointer

Tags: pointers, go, slice, reflect

When checking the `reflect.Kind()` of a slice, `reflect` correctly identifies it as a `slice` when not stored inside a pointer:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Dog struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    var dogs []Dog
    rDogs := reflect.ValueOf(dogs)
    fmt.Println(rDogs.Kind())
}
```

Output:

```
slice
```

However, when a slice is stored inside a pointer, `reflect.Kind()` identifies it as a `struct`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Dog struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    dogs1 := make([]Dog, 0)
    pointer := &dogs1
    printPointerValueKind(pointer)        

    var dogs2 []Dog
    pointer = &dogs2
    printPointerValueKind(pointer)
}

func printPointerValueKind(pointer interface{}) {
    if pointer != nil {
        rPointer := reflect.ValueOf(pointer)

        if rPointer.Kind() == reflect.Ptr {
            value := rPointer.Elem()
            rValue := reflect.ValueOf(value)
            fmt.Println(rValue.Kind())
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
struct
struct
```

My questions are:

1. Why does this happen?
2. Is there a way to store a slice inside a pointer and still have `reflect.Kind()` identify it as a `slice`?

Comment: @mkopriva I see, so that answers #1. Is #2 even possible then?

Comment: @mkopriva Thank you! That answers my questions! Could you please add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I think that you have once again gotten the right answer to the wrong question. See https://godoc.org/github.com/jmoiron/sqlx#Select which says that `dest` must "be a slice": you should be writing `var dogs1 []Dog` and then calling `Select` with `&dogs1`, and `Select` will fill in `Dogs1`. You're doing a lot of unnecessary work...

Comment: (BTW if I'm right, this is a classic example of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/166789).)

Comment: @torek Yup, `Select()` works with slices and even structs, but we want to enforce on our project that we will only be working with slices, specifically ones that have been initialized with `make()`.

Comment: Note that you can't detect whether a slice was initialized with `make` or just by initializing it: `var s = []T{}` is a non-nil slice `s` pointing to an underlying array with size 0, so it looks just like `var s []T` followed by `s = make([]T)`.

Comment: @torek No worries, we only care about non-nil slices. That was the term I meant to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1**. [`(reflect.Value).Elem()`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value.Elem) returns a [`reflect.Value`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#Value), which *is* a struct, and which does *not need* to be passed to [`reflect.ValueOf`](https://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#ValueOf) again if you're looking for the kind of the type that the value holds.

**2**. `rPointer.Elem().Kind()` should be enough for what you need.